# BigQuery: cost of querying tables partitioned by ingestion time vs date/timestamp partitioned

Tags: google-bigquery

We are trying to build (or better say rebuild) our DWH in the cloud based on BigQuery. We decided to use 'partitioned by date field' tables (like a 'created_date' field) for our raw data instead of ingestion time partitions because with this feature we can load data easely and then query it with "group by" partition date column, build datamarts bla bla bla. We supposed that this partition method will increase queries speed and reduce it cost (versus non-partitioned tables - yes), BUT we've discovered than when you querying table with WHERE by partition field (like 'select count(*) from table where created_date=current_date'), it will cost money.

Our old-style ingestion time partitioned table queries with WHERE _PARTITIONTIME  ='' were FREE! (like 'select count(*) from table where _PARTITIONTIME=current_date')

For example:

1) select value1 from table1 where _PARTITIONTIME = current_date

2) select value1 from table1 where created_date = current_date

3) select count(*) from table1 where _PARTITIONTIME = current_date

The second query costs more, because it will scan 2 columns. Its logical. But not fair((( The 3rd query is absolutely free btw!

This is very sad situation, because there is NO ANY WARNING about this 'side effect' in the documentation. This feature designed to make DB developers life easier (i guess), and it  positioned as best practice feature and highly recommended by Google. But nobody said that it will cost you additional money also!

So the question is can we somehow query date-field partitioned tables using partition key for free? Is there any other pseudocolumn or method of filtering by partition key available if you use date/timestamp field based partitioning?

(ps: you guys from google must add some pseudocolumn for the date/timestamp partition method if it does not exist).

Thnx!

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by  'side effect'?

Comment: The only free queries on BQ are ones that don't scan any data, are in your 1st TB of queries within the month, or are still available in the cache.  Your "free" query might only be free because there is no match on your `_PARTITIONTIME`, so it doesn't have to scan anything.

Comment: @rtenha , https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing 'Reading pseudo columns' is free in any cases.

Comment: 'side effect' means that 'we recommend to use this feature', but in fact you will need to pay more while scanning the same data. If you are end user and you want to query your data for one partition there is no actual difference will you use pseudocolumn for your query or phisical column for filtering if you dont want to visualize content of this column with date in a query result. If you've chosen partitioning by date column, you don't have ability to use pseudocolumn in your ETLs or queries. Every novice BigQuery engineer needs to know it. Now i know it and thinking how to live with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So the question is can we somehow query date-field partitioned tables
>   using partition key for free?

The answer is No, querying the partition will not be free.

> Is there any other pseudocolumn or method of filtering by partition
>   key available if you use date/timestamp field based partitioning?

If you want partitioning by date, this can only be achieved using ingestion-time partitioning with the _PARTITIONTIME pseudocolumn or using dates value in a selected date/timestamp value columns. Currently there is no alternative option available. Keep in mind that one of the main goals of partitioning is reducing the amount of data being scanned mainly by reducing the number of rows that are scanned.

> You guys from google must add some pseudocolumn for the date/timestamp partition method if it does not exist

I understand that you would like to have some pseudocolumn for the data column partitioned method, but could you please elaborate a bit more what values you would like to see in this partition in your original post?

**Edit**: A feature request has been opened on your behalf. You can follow it [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/144403604)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It would be nice if bigquery users could use some pseudocolumn like _PARTITIONTIME even if they use partitioning based on column, because this column can be 'timestamp' also not only  'date', but at the same time partitioning can be only by date so you need to cast DATE from your timestamp column anyway when you create table. And cast date from this field every time when you query the data.

Comment: Something like this would be nice: 
"'select count(clicks) from data where _PARTITIONTIME = '2019-01-01'" 
Instead of what i have to do now:
"select count(clicks) from data where date(my_ts_partitioning_field) = '2019-01-01' "
And in this case i need also always keep in mind on which column i partitioned my table if there are many ts columns. My business users don't need to know it as i think because it's hard to remember for every table. But they can remember easily that there is some ONE special column for these purposes.

Comment: There are a lot of reasons why this feature could be useful. In general - to reduce query cost if you don't need to qutput the data information and end users comfort .

Comment: Thank you very much) I hope this feature will appear in the future and will be very useful to everyone